# Mongoose.updateOne() not updating the value in a db

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I am new to nodejs. Mongoose.updateOne is not saving value into db. when i run this, it prints image uploaded in a console but it's not reflecting in a mongodb. I want to update my photo in a db

```
  var a = new photo();
    a.img.data = req.files.image.data
    a.img.contentType = req.files.image.mimetype;
    a._id = req.params.id;
```

Here is my updateOne method

```
     a.updateOne({_id:req.params.id}, function (err, result) {
                if (err){
                    console.log(err)
                }else{
                    res.send({ status: 1 }) 
                    console.log("image uploaded"+result)
                }
            });
```

Comment: You only specify filter, there is no update in `updateOne` parameters.

Comment: Can you tell me how to specify image data here

Comment: oh wait. your `a` is a document, not a model. So I think you can simply call `a.save(callback)` instead of `updateOne`

Answer (score 0):

Update: I failed to pass update syntax, and instead of using modelname (photo) i used variable name 'a'. Here it works

```
photo.updateOne({_id:req.params.id},{img:{data:req.files.image.data,contentType:req.files.image.mimetype}},function (err, result) {
                if (err){
                    console.log(err)
                }else{
                    res.send({ status: 1 }) 
                    console.log("image uploaded"+result)
                }
            });
```